# strtotime php function didn't give exact value

Tags: php, strtotime

I am saving to database the date and time as `timestamp` using time function. Now, I was trying to convert the date of the time stamp value to timestamp using `strtotime` function.  It wont give exact value as in the database

My code :

```
  $T= time() -> 11550500
     --> saved to database
     --> converting it to date : 11-11-2017
     --> use strtotime to convert 11-11-2017 to time stamp  $z= 124040400
```

I will not have `$T = $z` although they are holding the same date. So, what could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is likely that you're failing to consider the default timezone setting

Comment: @nasralla-mohammad Your question is not clear. You are trying to convert the date of the time stamp value to timestamp?

Comment: i am showing the timestamp value on my site as date ,,but when I convert the date back to timestamp for certain conditions it wont be the same.